# How to use if/else in a form

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to use if/else on a submit button given that if an employee time in is null a Sign In button will be shown otherwise Sign Out button is displayed. Below is my set_attendance form. The if/else does not work as expected. Could you please help how to make it work.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th> {{ __(' SL') }}</th>
                           <th> {{ __(' Employee Name') }}</th>
                           <th> {{ __('Action') }}</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @foreach($attendances as $key => $attd)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $attd['name'] }}</td>     
                                <td>
                                <form action="{{ route('attendance.timeclock') }}" method="post" name="department_add_form">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{ $attd['id'] }}">
                               
                                @if($timein[1]['timein'] == Null)
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i> {{ __('Sign IN') }}</button>
                                @else
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i> {{ __('Sign Out') }}</button>
                                @endif
                           
                                </form>
                                </td>   

                                
                            </tr>

                            @endforeach
                        
                       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Below is my timeclockcreate method in a controller

```
public function timeclockcreate(Request $request){

    $id = $request->input('id');
    $data['attendances'] = User::all()->toArray();

    $data['timein'] = User::query()
    ->leftjoin('attendances', 'attendances.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('attendances.*', 'users.*')
    ->orderBy('users.name', 'ASC')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

    return view('fms.attendances.set_attendance',$data)->with('id', $id)->with('message', 'Inserted successfully.');
 }
```

My attendance table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('attendances', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('created_by');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->time('timein')->nullable();
        $table->time('timeout')->nullable();
        $table->date('logdate');
        $table->string('status');   
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
         $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are accessing the same 'timein' for each employee with

```
$timein[1]['timein']
```

I'm guessing this is why it's not working.

You can search through the timein array to find the right timein row for the user you are currently looking at.

But instead you should set up an eloquent relationship with models that way you dont need to use joins. It simplifies queries a lot. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

@if( $attd['timein'] === NULL )

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.